# How to fetch all posts using tumblr API or Tumblr Rss feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, tumblr, fetch

I need to fetch all posts from a tumblr blog.
For example there  is a way for wordpress like: `blogRssUrl/paged={1}`, we can fetch all rss feeds page by page from a wordpress blog.

Is there a way something like this for tumblr?

Comment: Have you looked at the Tumblr API? http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Comment: I have looked it,the api requires authantication to fetch all contents of a tumblr blog.It means you can just fetch your blogs full content

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in your html or php.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://YourTumblrName.tumblr.com/js"></script>
```

It fetches the content of your tumblr into a page, but it not very flexible. I'm still trying to get the dates and tags fetched. And the image quality is not as good as in Tumblr...

Answer (score 1):

Use XML or JSON and [Tumblr API V1](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1)

XML: `http://yourtumblr.tumblr.com/api/read/`

JSON: `http://yourtumblr.tumblr.com/api/read/json`

Otherwise, there's probably a WP plugin that can handle the entire proces for you:
[Example WP plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tumblr-widget-for-wordpress/)